# How can I refactor and remove linear-gradient from inline CSS

Tags: html, css

I have inline CSS with background url that is being dynamically generated within a loop.

I want to add a linear gradient to the background image, but the only way I am able to do that is to add the `linear-gradient` alongside the background url.

I would like to remove the `linear-gradient` and add it in my `app.css` to be applied to the element while leaving the `url()` inline.

Is there anyway I can achieve that?

```
<div class="item cultureHeight" style="
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7)), url('assets/img/carousel/4.jpg') center center / cover;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7)), url('assets/img/carousel/4.jpg') center center / cover;
     background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7)), url('assets/img/carousel/4.jpg') center center / cover;
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7)), url('assets/img/carousel/4.jpg') center center / cover;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)), to(rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7))), url('assets/img/carousel/4.jpg') center center / cover;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7)), url('assets/img/carousel/4.jpg') center center / cover;
  ">
  <div class="row vflex">
    <div class="col-md-8 vcenter">
      <div class="item-content bottom">
        <div class="post-meta-top">
          <span class="label label-primary post-category">سياسة</span>
          <span class="post-reading"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2</span>
          <span class="post-location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> لبنان</span>
        </div>
        <div class="post-title"><h4><a href="article.html">إدارة أوباما تستعد لفرض أول عقوبات ضد إيران منذ الاتفاق النووي</a></h4></div>
        <div class="post-description">كشفت صحيفة "وول ستريت جورنال" اليوم عن اعتزام إدارة الرئيس الأمريكي باراك أوباما فرض عقوبات اقتصادية ضد إيران منذ إبرام اتفاق برنامج طهران النووي في يوليو</div>
        <div class="post-meta-bottom">
          <span class="post-bookmark"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o fa-2x"></i></a></span>
          <span class="post-author"><a href="#">جاد أبو ذكي</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** I created a new class `item-wrapper` and placed the `linear-gradient` inside of it, like so

```
.item-wrapper {
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7));
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7));
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)), to(rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7)));
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7));
      width: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
}
```

Then, I wrapped `div.item` within `div.item-wrapper` but it didn't change anything, the gradient is gone. And adding the pseudo selectors `before` and `after` don't change anything.

Comment: You'll need to apply the autoprocessing to the CSS file.

Comment: You could add another wrapper to contain either the background image or the gradient (or make the element create a stacking context and add a `::before` with `z-index: -1`).

Comment: I created a new class `item-wrapper` and placed the background gradient inside it. Then wrapped the `div.item` inside `div.item-wrapper` but that didn't work.

Comment: does this help? you can set the linear gradient in CSS, and read it and concatenate your `url()` background image via js. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbymVj

Comment: Or you could use a pseudo element for the gradient in your CSS and apply the image bg via JS https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRJQvm

Comment: It should be the other way around, I need to keep the `url()` inline in my HTML because I am getting from a PHP loop.

Comment: @MichaelCoker The second pen really helped. I just needed to tweak it around to fit my needs. Thank you. Please post an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one background on the main element, then the other on a pseudo element.

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div:before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 149, 219,0.7));
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" style="background-image: url(http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png)"></div>
```